# Map package implementation in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am having an issue within my react native project. I chose react native should work on iOS, android and web. However the issue is that the react native maps module does not work in the web view, it works fine in the android and iOS simulators but the web view throws an error. Error is as follows:

Uncaught TypeError:

```
react_native_1.UIManager.getViewManagerConfig is not a function
    at ./node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/decorateMapComponent.js (decorateMapComponent.js:29:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/MapMarker.js (MapMarker.js:29:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/index.js (index.js:37:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./screens/ItemScreen.js (HeatMapScreen.js:229:1)
```

I know it's the map module that is the issue because I can get all other features of the web app to work by commenting out the references to the map modules. i am implementing the map by the following code:

```
import ItemScreen from "./screens/ItemScreen";
import MapScreen from "./screens/MapScreen";
import HeatMapScreen from "./screens/HeatMapScreen";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();



export default function App() {
  // const isWeb = Platform.OS === "web";

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {/* <AppStack /> */}
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Discover" component={Discover} />

        {/* Comment out the next 3 lines to stop map view*/}
        <Stack.Screen name="ItemScreen" component={ItemScreen} />  
        <Stack.Screen name="MapScreen" component={MapScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="HeatMapScreen" component={HeatMapScreen} /> 

        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
        {/* <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} /> */}
        <Stack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ItineraryScreen" component={ItineraryScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="POIScreen" component={POIScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="FavoriteScreen" component={FavoriteScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

In my the 3 files that use the map which are `ItemScreen`, `MapScreen` and `HeatMapScreen` the mapview is imported as follows:

itemscreen.js: `import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";`

MapScreen.js: `import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker, Heatmap } from "react-native-maps";`

HeatMapScreen.js: `HeatMapScreen.js: import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker, Heatmap } from "react-native-maps";`

From what i can tell i have implemented these maps properly because they work on both iOS and android emulators, there error is only thrown in the web view for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

`react-native-maps` is designed to work on Android and iOS only. Behind the scene, it's binding to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/overview on Android and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapkit_for_appkit_and_uikit on iOS.

It's recommended to use Google Map Web SDK for web.

Comment: but because my app is react-native, doesn't the google map web sdk only work for react projects? not react native projects?

Comment: React Native maps do not support the web. Even if for Expo - https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/